# sql update based on count

Tags: sql-server, count, sql-update

I have a stored procedure that creates 4 temp tables and then returns records with a big select with inner joins at the end.  This is a cut-down version of the select that returns records.

```
SELECT R.*,
    REC.Status_Date as [Receive Status Date],
    RET.Status_Date as [Return Status Date]
FROM    #Records R
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Receive REC ON R.ID1 = REC.ID1 
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Return RET ON R.ID1 = RET.ID1 
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Submittal SUB ON SUB.RecID = REC.ID AND SUB.RetID = RET.ID
```

Note that there may be multiple #TEMP_Receive and #TEMP_Return records for the same ID1 and the #TEMP_Submittal table is what connects them.

I need to modify this procedure to include the number of holidays between the two status dates in two different tables that are included in the results. I can count the number of holidays from a separate table.  Something like this:

```
Select count(*)
From Holiday_List
Where Holiday_Date between REC.Status_Date and RET.Status_Date
```

I added a column Holiday_Count to the #Temp_Receive table.  How can I update the Holiday_Count column in the join with the count from the Holiday_List table?  I’ve tried something like this but from what I can find, this isn’t remotely valid SQL syntax.

```
UPDATE 
(   #Records R
    INNER JOIN #TEMP_Receive REC ON R.ID1 = REC.ID1 
    INNER JOIN #TEMP_Return RET ON R.ID1 = RET.ID1 
    INNER JOIN #TEMP_Submittal SUB ON SUB.RecID = REC.ID AND SUB.RetID = RET.ID )
SET REC.Holiday_Count = 
( SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM HOLIDAY_LIST HOL
  WHERE HOL.HOLIDAY_DATE between #TEMP_Receive.Status_Date AND #TEMP_Receive.Status_Date )
```

I’m running MS SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try to build `select` statement to see which rows will be updated. In your case the query may look like this.

```
SELECT R.*,
    REC.Status_Date as [Receive Status Date],
    RET.Status_Date as [Return Status Date],
    (Select count(*)
        From Holiday_List
        Where Holiday_Date between REC.Status_Date and RET.Status_Date) cnt
FROM    #Records R
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Receive REC ON R.ID1 = REC.ID1 
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Return RET ON R.ID1 = RET.ID1 
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Submittal SUB ON SUB.RecID = REC.ID AND SUB.RetID = RET.ID
```

2) When everything looks OK then replace `select` part with `update` statement.

```
update #Temp_Receive
    set Holiday_Count = (Select count(*)
        From Holiday_List
        Where Holiday_Date between REC.Status_Date and RET.Status_Date)
FROM    #Records R
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Receive REC ON R.ID1 = REC.ID1 
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Return RET ON R.ID1 = RET.ID1 
    INNER JOIN #Temp_Submittal SUB ON SUB.RecID = REC.ID AND SUB.RetID = RET.ID
```

Also note that multiple `inner join` implicitly suggest that same `ID1`s exist in all 4 tables.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Nice step wise answer. Thanks for the help!